# Alternative implementations with ternary operators, one liners

Tags: python, conditional-operator

I have a dictionary with some data and I would like to check if every field of `obligatory_data_fields` is included in this dictionary.

```
obligatory_data_fields = ("nickname", "name", "picture", "updated_at", "email", "email_verified",
                                 "iss", "sub", "aud", "iat", "exp")


a = {
  "nickname": "a",
  "name": "abcd@email.gr",
  "picture": "https://s.gravatar.com/avatar/a.png",
  "updated_at": "2020-05-07T08:44:10.091Z",
  "email": "abcd@email.gr",
  "email_verified": 'false',
  "iss": "x",
  "sub": "x",
  "aud": "x",
  "iat": 1588841051,
  "exp": 1588877051
}
```

So the most obvious thing is this one :

```
for data in obligatory_data_fields:
    if data in a:
        pass
    else:
        print('missing ', data)
```

I was wondering which are some better (efficient/faster) ways implementing this. 
I mean something like one liner [i know that the one liner that i wrote is wrong]

e.g `pass if data in a else print('missing ', data) for data in obligatory_data_fields`

Comment: `print('\n'.join([f'missing: {datum}' for datum in obligatory_data_fields if datum not in a]))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to validate, you can use `all`:

```
>>> all(field in a for field in obligatory_data_fields)
True
```

If you actually need the names of each missing field, you can use a list comprehension:

```
>>> missing = [field for field in obligatory_data_fields if field not in a]
>>> missing
[]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also convert the keys of the dictionary into a set and use set difference to get the missing values:

```
>>> set(obligatory_data_fields)-set(a)
>>> set() # Empty set, every key in obligatory_data_fields is present in 'a'
```